# Power BI embedded - passing authentication token or user credentials?

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

Is there a way to embed a Power BI report (in React), and specify parameters for the dataset?

We are using a set of stored procedures (in SQL Server) to return data. The stored procedures take user credentials, and return data based on the user (and role). We'd like to embed reports, but show the data specific to the current logged-in user.

Using RLS is not a viable option, since we already have our user management and authentication built in the underlying application.

Is this possible?

Comment: Parameters are common for all connections to the dataset. You can't set one set of parameter values for one user and another set for the other user.